# Max cache overflow file size custom option:** 0

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have a problem and when I run mongo db with docker or without docker I get that error

this is my command

```
docker run -d --net="host" --name mongo -v /etc/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf mongo -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

this is my /etc/mongod.conf

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
  port: 27017
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

mongodb logs

```
2019-08-13T06:44:50.454+0000 I STORAGE  [main] Max cache overflow file size custom option:** 0 </p>
```

Comment: This error seems to be introduced after I updated v4.0.11 to v4.0.12.

Comment: Does the appearance of this message have any impact on your `mongod` deployment (i.e. does it shutdown or behave unexpectedly afterward)? This appears to be informational rather than an error; some additional log context would be helpful.

Comment: It doesn't let me Don't let me fix it at all

Answer (score 1):

sudo chown -R {username} /data

## make the folder in mongodb dbpath have file write permission

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too, and after some investigation, my coworkers found that this seems to be a problem with v4.0.12. If you force it to use v4.0.11 or something, then it appears to work. For example, I'm setting up MongoDB via Ansible, and in my configuration playbook, I have something like this to dictate the version used for my mongoDB packages:

```
- name: Update repositories cache and install our mongodb packages
  apt:
    name: "{{ packages }}"
    update_cache: yes
  vars:
    packages:
      - mongodb-org=4.0.11
      - mongodb-org-server=4.0.11
      - mongodb-org-shell=4.0.11
      - mongodb-org-mongos=4.0.11
      - mongodb-org-tools=4.0.11
      - numactl
      - python-pip
  become: true
```

Comment: @Charlotte: Can you confirm what the impact was for your 4.0.12 deployment? This message should be informational rather than an error (i.e. safely ignorable).

Comment: @Stennie I might not be able to clearly answer your question, but I can tell you what I do know. We were having issues with the mongod service not starting on our instances, and upon checking the service status, the message posted by the OP was what we found. After switching to v4.0.11, the mongod service appeared to start without issue. I am relatively new to all this, so I am unsure what other information I could provide to you.

Comment: If you could share a gist or pastebin with any additional MongoDB log information between that message and shutdown, that would be helpful. The cache overflow message is logged at an informational level and should not be the direct cause of the MongoDB service failing to start. It would also be helpful to know your specific O/S version so I can try to repro the issue (I haven't been able to, yet).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this log message caused by Mongod attempting to write to a full partition. This was because mongo_global.log grew to 13 GB, all of the available space.